# Extending or Overriding CakePHP plugins without modifying original

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using a plugin (in this case Authake) and I would like to override/extend some of the functionality, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. I've managed to figure out how to customize the view (I created a folder '/app/views/plugins/authake' but I'm wondering how to modify/override/extend the Models and Compoenents of the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you want to extend the functionality of a model or perhaps a behavior in the plugin?

For example, we could extended the functionality of a **Sequence** behavior that is part of a **Sequence** plugin like so:

Create a new file in app/models/behaviors and call it extended_sequence.php

In this file, we'll create an **ExtendedSequenceBehavior** class that extends **SequenceBehavior** and overrides the **beforeFind** method. It will end up looking something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Import the SequenceBehavior from the Sequence Plugin
 */
App::import('Behavior', 'Sequence.Sequence');

/**
* Extended Sequence Behavior
*/
class ExtendedSequenceBehavior extends SequenceBehavior
{

  /**
   * Overrides the beforeFind function
   */
  public function beforeFind(&$model, $queryData)
  { 
    /**
     * Do something different here such as modify the query data
     */

    /**
     * You could still call the original function as well
     */
    parent::beforeFind(&$model, $queryData);
  }
}

?>
```

Note, that we have to import the Sequence behavior using Cake's App::import before we define the ExtendedBehavior class.

Update your model to use the extended class:

```
var $actsAs = array('ExtendedSequence');
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you